# jQuery animation with interval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want my piece of code to animate my menu out of the screen hence my -50px on scroll. and when not scrolling animate back in.

This is the code I have so far. but It only works on every time I refresh my browser.

```
var $menu = $(".sticky-nav");
var topAnim = $menu.css("top");
var scrollStopped;

var fadeInCallback = function () {
    if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(scrollStopped);
    }

    scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
        $( ".sticky-nav" ).animate({
   top: "20px"
  }, 300);
});
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (!$menu.is(":animated") && topAnim == "20px") {
                $( ".sticky-nav" ).animate({
   top: "-50px"
  }, 300);

    } else {
        fadeInCallback.call(this);
    }
});
```

jsfiddle.net/B997S

Comment: could you please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Replace `setTimeout` with `setInterval()`! Read [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) documentation!

Comment: Here is a Jsfiddle what what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/B997S/ as you can see there the menu moves up but not back down. and it needs to check every scroll for that to happen. and animate back when not scrolling. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues in your code.

```
Replaced topAnim in the below line with $menu.css("top") as topAnim always returned a constant.

if (!$menu.is(":animated") && $menu.css("top") == "20px") {

Next issue was

scrollStopped = setInterval(function () { // this is the right format
```

Please check the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/B997S/1/

Comment: Almost. It returns now. but it should only animate back when i stop scrolling. and animate out the screen with scrolling. It should do that every scroll so to say